# play next video in an array on "ended"

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ipad, html

I have an array of videos, and when one ends, the next in the array should play.
I've found this script:

```
function myNewSrc() {
    var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
    myVideo.src =
        "http://cheerioscoupons.info/wp-content/uploads/_Cheerios-Coupons-1-300x283.jpg";
    myVideo.load();
    myVideo.play();
}
function myAddListener(){
    var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
    myVideo.addEventListener('ended',myNewSrc,false);
}
```

but I'm having trouble implementing it in my current script, which is,

```
var numb = $(this).index(),
    videos = [
        "images/talking1.m4v",
        "images/talking2.m4v",
        "images/talking1.m4v",
        "images/talking2.m4v",
        "images/talking1.m4v",
        "images/talking2.m4v"
    ],
    myVideo = document.getElementById("myVid");
    myVideo.src = videos[numb];
    myVideo.load();
    setTimeout(function(){
        myVideo.play();
    }, 200);
```

So, two questions:

1. Are they interfering? The first one doesn't change the video at all.
2. How can I combine these so that the next video called is the next in the array?

Comment: one problem, you redeclare the video array each call...

Comment: One another problem: `document.getElementsByTagName("video");` will return an array of elements, not one single DOM element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1.**
 `document.getElementsByTagName` will return an array of elements, not one. So

```
var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName("video");
myVideo.addEventListener('ended',myNewSrc,false);    //wrong

var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName("video");
myVideo.load();   //wrong
myVideo.play();   //wrong
```

What it should be is:

```
myVideo[0].load()   //if there is only one

for(var i=0;i<myVideo.length;i++){
    myVideo[i].load();    //if there is more
}
```

**2.**
Play another video after `ended`,

```
var videos = [
    "images/talking1.m4v",
    "images/talking2.m4v",
];
function playArray(index,ele,array,listener){
    ele.removeEventListener(listener||0);
    ele.src = array[index];
    ele.load();
    ele.play();
    index++;
    if(index>=array.length){
        index=0;
    }
    listener = ele.addEventListener('ended',function(){
        playArray(index,ele,array,listener);
    },false);
}
playArray(0,document.getElementById("myVid"),videos);
```

**LIVE DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/qeLcD/ (Replaced with an array with text instead of viedos)

Comment: where exactly are these supposed to go? (since theyre not the first things to be done, i have them more towards the end of a long script[which is mostly click effects that interact with the video])

Comment: @Nata2haMayan2 - Put all the things in `<head>`, and just call `playArray()` when you need it.

Answer (score 1):

I modified the videos input using multiple file input so that the user can select the files.

https://jsfiddle.net/geqd31pu/

```
<input id="file" type="file" multiple>    
<button onclick="play()">play</button>    
<video id="video" src="" autoplay controls></video>    
<script>
let index = 0
video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0]
play = () => {
  const files = document.getElementById('file').files
  const file = files[index++ % files.length]
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(file)
  video.src = url
  video.load()
}
video.addEventListener('ended', play, false)
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

play   let index = 0 video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0] play = () => { const files = document.getElementById('file').files const file = files[index++ % files.length] const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(file) video.src = url video.load() } video.addEventListener('ended', play, false)