# Javascript onended is detecting the end of the video

Tags: javascript, html, video

Everything in my code works. It just doesn't switch to the next song/video after finishing the current one. I have tried adding an `onended` event handler (in the  tag and in JavaScript) but failed. I also tried jQuery but it did't work. For some reasons it doesn't change songs at the end of the song. Instead, it will replay the same song over and over again.

```html
<video id="vid" src="main/" playsinline autoplay loop>
  <script>
   var video = document.currentScript.parentElement;
   video.volume = 0.1;  
   var lastSong = null;
   var selection = null;
   var playlist = ["main/songn.mp4", "main/songl.mp4", "/main/songt.mp4", "/main/songf.mp4"]; // List of Songs
   var video = document.getElementById("vid"); 
   video.autoplay=true;
   video.addEventListener("ended", selectRandom); 

   function selectRandom(){
    while(selection == lastSong){ 
     selection = Math.floor(Math.random() * playlist.length);
    }
    lastSong = selection; 
    video.src = playlist[selection]; 

   }

   selectRandom(); 
   video.play();

  </script>
</video>
```

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10668399/play-next-video-in-an-array-on-ended

Comment: that doesnt help.

Comment: `var video = document.currentScript.parentElement;` I've never seen `currentScript` used in such a way, that's thinking out of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to remove the `loop` parameter from the video tag if you want to trigger the *end event* ([doc](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#ended-playback)):

```
<video id="vid" src="main/" playsinline autoplay>
```

(Your code will handle the loop by loading a new song when one ended.)

BTW, keep `var video = document.getElementById("vid");` to refer to your `<video>` tag, it's shorter and cleaner than the first declaration.

Comment: might benefit from a quote from [specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#ended-playback) : *"A media element is said to have ended playback when: [...]  - The current playback position is the end of the media resource, and [...] - The media element does not have a loop attribute specified."*